# Simple Age Calculator

Tags: c#, beginner, datetime

I have written an age calculator that takes a `birthDate` as input.

I'd like a general review of this. I'm especially concerned about the `message` variable and the lines after the `try/catch` statement.

```
namespace Age
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter your birtdate: ");
                    DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    int Days = (DateTime.Now.Year * 365 + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear) - (birthDate.Year * 365 + birthDate.DayOfYear);
                    int Years = Days / 365;
                    string message = (Days >= 365) ? "Your age: " + Years + " years" : "Your age: " + Days + " days";

                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date.\n");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Exit? (y/n)");
                string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

                if (userValue == "y")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something specific that you would like a feedback about your code or you just want a general review ?

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:homework]? Leap-years contain 366 days.

Comment: I just wanted a general review. Still, I'm a little uncertain about the "string message"-variable and the lines after the try-catch statement. I've never really terminated an application like this before.

This is not homework, just me programming on hobby basis.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. You should give the user some format to follow when entering their birthday

   ```
   Console.Write("Enter your birthdate (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
   ```
2. You should give the user a way to close the program. While this isn't incredibly necessary for simple learning programs, it is a good habit to get into.
3. You should avoid throwing exceptions, they break up your program's flow. Certainly use them where necessary, but this is not one of those places. Exceptions should be used in situations when your function doesn't have the ability to handle a situation/error.

   In the following snippet, I've declared the DateTime object, and a Boolean which will tell us if the string entered by the user was able to be parsed. Notice how I am calling the TryParse Method. The TryParse method takes in a string, and an `out` `DateTime` `object`. This is important, the out keyword is a bit more advanced than you have come accross. It is a keyword which implements functionality programmers were used to in C using pointers. Suffice to say that this function will set whatever object you pass in, to be the parsed value.

   ```
   DateTime birthDate;
   bool succeeded = DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out birthDate);
   ```

   Because the TryParse method returns a bool you can just use this in an if statement which is conditional on the TryParse returning true.

   ```
   if(DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out birthDate))
   {
       // more stuff
   }
   else
       Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date.");
   ```
4. I noticed you used `\n` in your program. While I will say that I am guilty of using this all the time, you should actually use `Environment.NewLine`. The reason is because of in-consistency of newline/carriage returning in different programs. `Environment.NewLine` always uses the proper line ending.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date." + Environment.NewLine);
   ```
5. You can use + or - operators on DateTime objects which results in a TimeSpan object

   ```
   TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
   ```

   TimeSpan objects have properties like Days, Hours. the calculation done, does take into consideration leap years.
6. Printing to the console can be made easier by sending parameters to be inserted into your string.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Your age: {0} years and {1} days", (int)(age.Days/365.25), age.Days % 365.25);
   ```

---

Over all, your program could look like this. Note: I didn't programatically address the issue of the user escaping your program, I noticed you updated your OP with that.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter your birtdate (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    DateTime birthDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out birthDate))
    {
        TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
        Console.WriteLine("Your age: {0} years and {1} days", (int)(age.Days/365.25), age.Days % 365.25);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date." + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

---

**Edit**: This is of-course personal taste, but I dislike (what I consider to be unnessary brackets taking up newlines).

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date." + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Some people prefer that, I just am not, and that is up to every coder to decide. If I was to put brackets arround that, I would probably do it this way

```
else
    { Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date." + Environment.NewLine); }
```

Comment: I think that even better than `NewLine` would be to use a separate second `Console.WriteLine()` for the second newline.

Comment: Also, I don't think using 365.25 makes sense here. For example, `700 % 365.25` is `334.75`, I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: 3. Your if-else statement looks really weird to me since the `if` part is using bracket and the `else` one don't.

Comment: @svick I almost suggested that, but I wanted him to be aware of Environment.Newline. Also, the 365.25 was just to account for leapyear.

Comment: @Marc-Andre its up to you to bracket how you feel, while they don't match, I think single lines look ugly when surrounded by brackets. If you wanted to you could even put brackets at the beginning and ending of the line.

Comment: @BenVlodgi `I think single lines look ugly when surrounded by brackets.` well I won't bother you with that again since I strongly disagree with that, since it's a personal taste!

Comment: @Marc-Andre yes it is just a coder choice, I did add an edit showing what I meant by my earlier statement.

Answer (score 18):

I was going to edit my other answer, but instead I'm going to take a different approach - I mean, I'll push it to the extreme ;)

---

> ## Warning
>
> *I'll push it to the extreme* is to be taken literally. This solution doesn't aim at solving the *simple age calculator* problem, rather at showing how one would architect a SOLID application - *if the goal is just to calculate the difference between two dates, this is absolute overkill*. If the goal is to learn how to write good OOP using a trivial/simple problem as an excuse...
>
> **Buckle up, you're in for a ride.**

---

#### static void Main(string[] args)

As you know by now, this is your application's *entry point*. When this `static` method returns, the program ends. To terminate your program, simply use `return;` in this method, or structure your program flow so that *normal exit* simply causes the main thread (imagine a cursor running each instruction sequentially - or *step through* your code in the debugger) to reach the bottom of the `Main` method.

This method being `static`, if you're going to call anything outside of it, it's going to have to be `static` as well. If you're writing *procedural* code, it doesn't matter.

If you want *object-oriented* code, the `Main` method will probably have a very high *level of abstraction*, and will read like pseudo-code, if not like plain English.

The method revolves around the idea that it's a program's birth, life, and death.

*Dependency Injection* (DI) disciples (guilty!) call this entry point, the *composition root*. This is where you *instantiate* the application (and its *dependencies*), and run it.

Simplified to the extreme:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new MyApplication();
    app.Run();
}
```

What's in the `Run()` method?

```
public class MyApplication
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        // initialisation here
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // app logic here
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Run` method is *not* `static`. It exists only as a *member* of the *interface* of an *object* defined by this `MyApplication` class - in other words, you need an *instance* of `MyApplication` to call this method.

In this case the *application logic* part will feature our main loop, from which we will exit based on a condition.

```
public void Run()
{
    var keepRunning = true;

    while(keepRunning)
    {
        // application logic
        keepRunning = false; // exit
    }
}
```

At this point, we've reached a *point of no return*. Anything else we code in the `Run` method will impact maintainability, testability, and readability. Better keep it to a minimum.

---

The key resides in *delegating the work*. The `MyApplication` class cannot do its work alone without using the `new` keyword, which would *increase coupling*, and without doing the work all by itself, which would *decrease cohesion*. Since we want *low coupling* and *high cohesion*, we'll start by avoiding the use of `static` methods and of the `new` keyword.

> **Why?**
>
> *Good code is testable code*. You'll want to be able to write tests for the code you write - whether you write these tests or not, writing *testable* code will tend to produce code that is more *cohesive* and less *coupled*.
>
> <sub>**See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085419/1188513</sub>

#### IUserInteraction

We know we want to use the console to interact with the user, but in order to test our application logic, we'll want to be able to substitute the user's input for whatever our tests need.

```
public interface IUserInputProvider
{
    string GetUserInput(string prompt);
    T GetUserInput<T>(string prompt, IUserInputValidator<T> validator);
}
```

With that - and that only, we already have enough to go back to the `MyApplication` class:

```
public class MyApplication
{
    private readonly IUserInputProvider _inputProvider;

    public MyApplication(IUserInputProvider inputProvider)
    {
        _inputProvider = inputProvider;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var keepRunning = true;

        while(keepRunning)
        {
            var prompt = "Enter your birth date:";
            var input = _inputProvider.GetUserInput(prompt); // no validation for now
            // ...

            keepRunning = false; // exit
        }
    }
}
```

I'll get back to the `IUserInputValidator<T>` later.

> **Mocking**
>
> `GetUserInput` is a method that returns a `string`. Nothing more, nothing less. We *know* that we want to call `Console.ReadLine()`, but that's an *implementation detail* that the `MyApplication` class does not need to know about.
>
> If we were to write a test to see if the `Run` method effectively exits when the user enters "y", we would not bring up a console and wait for someone to enter "y" - instead we would set up a *mock* - a "fake" implementation of the `IUserInputProvider` interface that returns "y" when we ask it to `GetUserInput`.

**Implementation**

The concrete implementation we're going to be using will use the console. Nothing prevents making another concrete implementation that pops up a dialog window instead - as long as we use a `prompt` and return a `string`, anything can work. This means the implementation(s) can be modified in every possible way, the only assumption the `MyApplication` class makes is that there's a `GetUserInput` method that takes a `string prompt` and returns a `string`.

This could be an implementation:

```
public class ConsoleUserInputProvider : IUserInputProvider
{
    public string GetUserInput(string prompt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public T GetUserInput<T>(string prompt, IUserInputValidator<T> validator)
    {
        string input;
        T result;

        var isValidInput = false;
        while(!isValidInput)
        {
            input = GetUserInput(prompt);
            isValidInput = validator.Validate(input, out result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Where `IUserInputValidator` is yet another abstraction that exposes a `bool Validate(string input)` method.

Let's make it a generic interface:

```
public interface IUserInputValidator<T>
{
    bool Validate(string input, out T result);
}
```

One could implement it like this:

```
public class BirthDateValidator : IUserInputValidator<DateTime>
{
    public bool Validate(string input, out DateTime result)
    {
        return DateTime.TryParse(input, out result);
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public enum YesNoResult
{
    Unknown,
    Yes,
    No
}

public class YesNoValidator : IUserInputValidator<YesNoResult>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, YesNoResult> _values;

    public YesNoValidator(IDictionary<string, YesNoResult> values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }

    public bool Validate(string input, out YesNoResult result)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("input", "input string is empty.");
        }

        var lowerCase = input.Substring(0, 1).ToLower();
        
        var isValue = values.TryGetValue(lowerCase, out result);
        if (!isValue)
        {
            result = YesNoResult.Unknown;
        }
        
        return (result != YesNoResult.Unknown);
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, this approach produces very focused and specialized code - code that does one thing, so well, that it can't possibly even *need* to change. And yet it remains extensible - you could *decorate* any `Validator` implementation with, say, a `ValidationLoggerDecorator` that can log all failed validations:

```
public class ValidationLoggerDecorator<T> : IUserInputValidator<T>
{
    private readonly IUserInputValidator<T> _validator;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ValidationLoggerDecorator(IUserInputValidator<T> validator, ILogger logger)
    {
        _validator = validator;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public bool Validate(string input, out T result)
    {
        var isValid = _validator.Validate(input, out result);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            _logger.Info(string.Format("Validation failed for input '{0}'.", input));
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Let's step back and take a look at what we've got here:

- The code remains focused on a *single responsibility* - following the *Single Responsibility Principle*.
- The extensibility depicted with the decorator example, is a side-effect of the *Open/Closed* principle: a class is closed for modification, open for extension.
- The fact that the `MyApplication` class can work with any implementation of the `IUserInputProvider` interface, regardless of what dependencies that implementation might have, is a side-effect of the *Liskov Substitution Principle*.
- Following the *Interface Segregation Principle* makes our interfaces be very focused as well, *ideally* exposing only a single member. This point greatly influences *cohesion*.
- The fact that all *implementations* ("concrete" classes) *depend on abstractions*, and that these *dependencies* are *injected* into their constructor, is following the Dependency Inversion Principle*.

Together, these 5 points spell [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)).

---

The `IUserInputValidator` we're passing to the `GetUserInput()` method, must come from somewhere. But if we create a `new BirthDateValidator()` our class will be *tightly coupled* with that specific implementation, and it will become very hard to test the `GetUserInput()` method and control validation from the outside.

The `MyApplication` class can receive the validators it needs in its constructor, and we can extract some of the logic from the `Run` method, into their own private methods:

```
public class MyApplication
{
    private readonly IUserInputProvider _inputProvider;
    private readonly IUserInputValidator<DateTime> _dateValidator;
    private readonly IUserInputValidator<YesNoResult> _confirmationValidator;

    public MyApplication(IUserInputProvider inputProvider, 
                         IUserInputValidator<DateTime> dateValidator, 
                         IUserInputValidator<YesNoResult> confirmationValidator)
    {
        _inputProvider = inputProvider;
        _dateValidator = dateValidator;
        _confirmationValidator = confirmationValidator;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var keepRunning = true;

        while(keepRunning)
        {
            var date = GetBirthDate();
            // ...

            keepRunning = !GetExitConfirmation();
        }
    }

    private DateTime GetBirthDate()
    {
        var prompt = "Enter your birth date:";
        var input = _inputProvider.GetUserInput(prompt, _dateValidator);
        
        return DateTime.Parse(input);
    }

    private bool GetExitConfirmation()
    {
        var prompt = "Exit (Y|N)?";
        var input = _inputProvider.GetUserInput(confirmPrompt, _confirmationValidator);

        return input == YesNoResult.Yes;
    }
}
```

Notice how the constructor could easily get bloated with possibly as many validators as there are things we want to get from the user. 3 constructor parameters is probably ok. More than that though, and I would be tempted to extract the validators into their own object, so as to keep the message clear: the `MyApplication` class *needs* validators - it doesn't *do* validation.

Let's extract them anyway to see what we get:

```
public class UserInputValidation
{
    private readonly IUserInputValidator<DateTime> _dateValidator;
    private readonly IUserInputValidator<YesNoResult> _confirmationValidator;

    public UserInputValidation(IUserInputValidator<DateTime> dateValidator, 
                               IUserInputValidator<YesNoResult> confirmationValidator)
    {
        _dateValidator = dateValidator;
        _confirmationValidator = confirmationValidator
    }

    public IUserInputValidator<DateTime> DateValidator { get { return _dateValidator; } }
    public IUserInputValidator<YesNoResult> ConfirmationValidator { get { return _confirmationValidator; } }
}
```

---

Because the actual calculation algorithm would, by itself, be a *reason to change*, it's best to encapsulate it in its own class.

[@svick's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44627/23788) could be an implementation of some `IAgeCalculator` interface.

The `MyApplication` class now looks like this:

```
public class MyApplication
{
    private readonly IUserInputProvider _inputProvider;
    private readonly IAgeCalculator _calculator;
    private readonly UserInputValidation _validation;

    public MyApplication(IUserInputProvider inputProvider,
                         IAgeCalculator calculator, 
                         UserInputValidation validation)
    {
        _inputProvider = inputProvider;
        _calculator = calculator;
        _validation = validation;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var keepRunning = true;

        while(keepRunning)
        {
            var date = GetBirthDate();
            DisplayAge(date);

            keepRunning = !GetExitConfirmation();
        }
    }

    private DateTime GetBirthDate()
    {
        var prompt = "Enter your birth date:"; 
        var input = _inputProvider.GetUserInput(prompt, _validation.DateValidator);
        
        return DateTime.Parse(input);
    }

    private void DisplayAge(DateTime date)
    {
        var result = _calculator.GetDifferenceInYearsAndDays(date, DateTime.Today);
        var message = string.Format("Your age: {0} years and {1} days", result.Item1, result.Item2);
        _inputProvider.ShowMessage(message);
    }

    private bool GetExitConfirmation()
    {
        var prompt = "Exit (Y|N)?"; 
        var input = _inputProvider.GetUserInput(confirmPrompt, _validation.ConfirmationValidator);

        return input == YesNoResult.Yes;
    }
}
```

---

The above assumes a `ShowMessage` method was added to the `IUserInputProvider` interface; this method is implemented like this:

```
public void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

---

Now, the `Main` method can serve its purpose: *compose* the application!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = new ConsoleInputProvider();
    var calculator = new AgeCalculator();
    var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("logger"); // gets a NLog logger
    var dateValidator = new ValidationLoggerDecorator(new BirthDateValidator(), logger);
    var yesNoValues = new Dictionary<string, YesNoResult>
                          {
                              { "y", YesNoResult.Yes },
                              { "n", YesNoResult.No }
                          };
    var confirmationValidator = new YesNoValidator(values);
    var validation = new UserInputValidation(dateValidator, confirmationValidator);

    var app = new MyApplication(input, calculator, validation);
    app.Run();
}
```

As you can see, *inversion of control* makes it easy to change our minds and swap the `dateValidator` for a simple `BirthDateValidator`, or to write a unit test that will only test how date validation operates, or only how age gets calculated, independently of everything else, without requiring user intervention, and with every dependency under full control.

Of course the *composition root* for this trivial application is instantiating the objects manually (a.k.a. *poor man's DI*), and it's quite manageable. For a bigger application, you could leave this daunting task to your favorite IoC container, leaving your `Main` method looking something like this (here using Ninject):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyApplicationNinjectModule());
    var app = kernel.Get<MyApplication>();
    app.Run();
}
```

The entire application's dependency graph gets resolved in a single method call - Ninject isn't the fastest at that, but its nice syntax and great extensibility make it a solid candidate to consider. If you don't know what a `StandardKernel` does, the above code might seem *automagical* if I tell you that it does the exact same thing as the previous snippet.

And that's long enough.

Comment: You call both `DateTime.TryParse(input)` and `DateTime.Parse(input)`. You also have `input.ToLower() == "y"` in `YesNoValidator` and `input.ToUpper() == "Y"` This is not dry. You really need something like F# `Option` or use `null` as return value or something similar.

Comment: Doesn't "ideally exposing only a single member" imply that everything can be declared as a delegate instead of as an interface? For example, instead of `IUserInputProvider inputProvider`, `Func<string,string> GetUserInput` (input parameter is the prompt and return value is the user input)? And instead of `IUserInputValidator confirmationValidator`, `Func<string,bool> Validate`? With interfaces, you need to declare the interface, declare the method in the interface, declare a separate class which implements the interfaces, construct an instance of the class, ...

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca I thought of turning `Validate()` into `Validate<TValue>()` and adding an `out TValue value` parameter, but I didn't, because I wanted the post to focus on SOLID - getting into `out` parameters and generics was going to be way overboard... already is ;)

Comment: ... with delegates you just declare the delegate type, or use one of the `Func<>` overloads to declare the delegate type; and the method which implements the delegate can be anything, even just a static method of the Main or Application or Test class.

Comment: Maybe teaching/implementing this using interfaces instead of delegates is a hang-over from Java?

Comment: @ChrisW lol, this is overkill in many, many ways; indeed, delegates would be simpler - the idea was to use the OP's code/project as a "small app" to show how one would use these techniques to make a "bigger app" (as explained in [*Is decoupling necessary for very small applications?*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/is-decoupling-necessary-for-very-small-applications/42094#42094)). OTOH I do have a tendency to underexploit delegates and overuse interfaces, you have a point :)

Comment: I'd be inclined to use an interface (or class) instead of a delegate (or method) iff there are two related/codependent method rather than just one.

Comment: Your `keepRunning = GetExitConfirmation();` seems to be incorrect. `GetExitConfirmation` returns `true` if the user wants to exit, not if the user wants to keep running the program.

Comment: @comecme fixed, thanks! Ironically, a simple unit test would have caught that bug in a splitsecond :)

Comment: This might be the longest answer I've ever seen on CR

Answer (score 17):

> ```
> Console.Write("Enter your birtdate: ");
> DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
> ```

Your `catch` block looks like it's assuming a `ParseException` that would be thrown by the above `DateTime.Parse` call. Thus, it would be better to be explicit about it:

```
catch(ParseException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid date.\n");
}
```

This way, if *another exception type* is thrown somewhere else in the loop, you will not be displaying a misleading message.

Now, how about using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and specify what would be the expected date format?

```
Console.Write("Enter your birtdate (yyyy-MM-dd): ");
DateTime birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That's all great, too many things are happening in a single line of code here:

- `Controle.ReadLine()` is getting the console input
- `DateTime.Parse` | `DateTime.ParseExact` is parsing the console input

You should break this down into 2 separate instructions:

```
Console.Write("Enter your birtdate (yyyy-MM-dd): ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that I'm using `var` for brevety here, `input` is a `string` and `birthDate` is a `DateTime`.

The next step would be to *extract a method* out of these few lines - have a method called `GetBirthDate` that returns a `DateTime`, or throws a `ParseException` that your `catch` block can handle.

Answer (score 11):

To calculate the date difference properly, you need to take leap years into account. And you need to use the proper rules for deciding when is a leap year. Fortunately, the .Net libraries already know all that.

So, how to do it? Find out the person's last birthday and then calculate the year difference since the birth date and then the day difference until today. In code:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> GetDifferenceInYearsAndDays(DateTime birth, DateTime today)
{
    if (birth > today)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var thisYearBirthday = new DateTime(today.Year, birth.Month, birth.Day);
    var lastBirthday =
        thisYearBirthday <= today ? thisYearBirthday : thisYearBirthday.AddYears(-1);

    int years = lastBirthday.Year - birth.Year;
    int days = (today - lastBirthday).Days;

    return Tuple.Create(years, days);
}
```

This might be more complicated than your code, but it's correct, and I also think that it's more readable.

The code is in a separate method, to follow [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

---

One more thing: whenever you use `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.Today`), you should access that property only once and store that value in a variable, or something. Otherwise, your code might have a really weird bug while everyone else is celebrating New Year.

Comment: I just realized that this won't work if the birth date is on 29 February. Not sure how to fix that, while still keeping the code relatively simple.

Comment: Assuming that in a leap year the birthday is on 28 February: `thisYearBirthday = new DateTime(today.Year, birth.Month, birth.Day > DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.year, birth.Month) ? DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.year, birth.Month) : birth.Day)`. But introducing a variable for DaysInMonth would be better. Maybe this would make the code not so simple anymore