# Finding the lowest and highest values in an array... with "Poor Man's DI"

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am practicing my object oriented knowledge, so I created a very simple program that determines which is the lowest and highest number inside array.

This is my main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("How many numbers would you like to enter?: ");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] arr = new int[num];

        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++ )
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number {0}: ", (x+1));
            arr[x] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Lowest (1) \nHighest (2) \nEnter choice: ");
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        Math math;

        if (choice == 1){
            math = new Math(new HighestNumber(), arr);
            Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + math.returnAnswer());
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            math = new Math(new LowestNumber(), arr);
            Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + math.returnAnswer());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The `IMathPerformer` interface:

```
interface IMathPerformer
{
    int getAnswer(int[]arr);
}
```

...and its implementations:

```
class HighestNumber : IMathPerformer
{
    public int getAnswer(int[]arr)
    {
        int highNum = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x<arr.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            if(arr[highNum] > arr[x+1])
            {
                highNum = (x + 1);
            }
        }

        return arr[highNum];
    }
}

class LowestNumber : IMathPerformer
{
    public int getAnswer(int[]arr)
    {
        int lowNum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            if (arr[lowNum] < arr[x + 1])
            {
                lowNum = (x + 1);
            }
        }

        return arr[lowNum];
    }
```

The `Math` class:

```
class Math
{
    private int[] arr;
    private readonly IMathPerformer imathPerformer;
    public Math(IMathPerformer imathPerformer, int[]arr)
    {
        this.imathPerformer = imathPerformer;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    public int returnAnswer()
    {
        return imathPerformer.getAnswer(arr);
    }
}
```

I just want to know if I am doing right or this is a bad practice. If it is bad, it would be greatly appreciated if you could point out why and how to fix it and add some more advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, kudos for exercising OOP and DI! Coding against interfaces is going to make your life easier in so many wonderful ways!

I agree, [no problem is too simple to solve with SOLID principles](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42094/23788), *especially* for learning purposes. Shifting from procedural to object-oriented code takes practice.

The first key to proper OOP is *abstraction*.

These are the *abstractions* I see in your code:

- `IMathPerformer`, an interface that *gets some answer* given an `int[]`. Implementations are responsible for computing the `Min` or `Max` value, or any other operation that returns an `int` given an `int[]`.

That's unfortunately all. Unfortunate, because I see these *requirements* in your code:

- Collecting the data (the `int[]` to work with)
- Determining what to do with the data
- Outputting the result

And from these requirements, I see these *responsibilities*:

- Interacting with the console

  - Validating user input
- Collecting the data
- Knowing what to do with the data

  - Creating the menu with each available command
- Performing the appropriate command
- Outputting the result
- Coordinating the sequence of operations

If a class should be *responsible* for one thing, then there should be at least 5-6 types in this program.

Back to your code: the `Math` class doesn't seem to really "fit in" anywhere in the above list - or rather, it's redundant: the command to execute is already known when the class gets created, and it acts as a middle man that doesn't really do anything that the `IMathPerformer` can't do just as well without it; it's *forcing* dependency injection, but there's nothing that justifies it because the *abstraction level* in the calling code is too low.

*Abstraction levels* are crucial. The entry point of your program (the `Main` method) should have a very high abstraction level, and is usually pretty short. For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = CreateApp(args);
    app.Run();
}
```

We create an `app` object and call its `Run` method. The `CreateApp` method might look like this:

```
private static ArrayOpsApp CreateApp(string[] args)
{
    var validator = new UserInputValidator();
    var console = new ConsoleUserInterface(validator);
    var argsParser = new CommandLineArgsParser();
    var collector = new IntConsoleCollector(console, argsParser, args);

    var commands = new[] {
        new MinValueFinder(),
        new MaxValueFinder(),
        new AvgCalculator(),
        new StdDevCalculator(),
        //...
    };
    var commandSelector = new ConsoleCommandSelector(console, commands);
    var app = new ArrayOpsApp(console, collector, commandSelector);

    return app;
}
```

This method has a very special role: it's the only place in the application we're allowed to `new` up one of our concrete types - everywhere else, we are coding against interfaces. It's the application's *composition root*, where we *compose* the application's *dependency graph*.

Just by looking at this code, you can get a grasp of how the entire application is structured, because every type has its dependencies injected through the constructor.

You know that the `IntConsoleCollector` is the specific implementation for what the rest of the code sees as some abstract `IDataCollector`, or even a generic `IDataCollector<int>`.

You know that the user input will be validated somehow.

Because that type takes a `ConsoleUserInterface` implementation for what might be its `IUserInterface` dependency, we know that the type needs an object that's responsible for dealing with UI concerns, and because it takes an `IArgsParser`, we can infer that we can specify the input with command-line arguments and that the collector might just spit them back and skip prompting the user for them. Perhaps it's also used for parsing the user's input if the `args` array is empty or doesn't contain anything useful - but that's an implementation detail.

We know exactly which commands will be available for the `commandSelector`, and again we know that the selector will work with the console, because we're giving it `console` for its `IUserInterface` dependency; we can infer that the selector will be iterating the available commands to create a menu interface using the console.

The method then injects the collector and the selector dependencies into a new `ArrayOpsApp`, which will obviously be responsible for consuming these dependencies and coordinating the sequence of operations.

---

The `Main` method in your code has both hands into that sequence of operations; it's responsible for collecting the data, dealing with the user's input, determining which concrete types to use, ... it does pretty much everything *except* actually computing the min/max values.

You *started* implementing DI, but stopped somewhere along the way. Half-implemented DI unfortunately doesn't get half the benefits of DI: the only *testable* code is the code that you've extracted into an interface... which makes the `IMathPerformer` interface pretty much useless, since if you test the implementations you don't really need the interface it's implementing.

There is no way to write a test that documents what happens when the user enters invalid input. Sad, because you would have found out that you get a `FormatException` when the [int.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) call fails.

Because of the high *coupling* and low *cohesion* of the `Main` method, most of the code can't be unit-tested at all. You'll want to reverse that, and achieve *low coupling and high cohesion*.

SOLID isn't everything though: it doesn't really touch on the minute implementation details. This is where things like the DRY principle kick in:

> ```
> if (choice == 1){
>     math = new Math(new HighestNumber(), arr);
>     Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + math.returnAnswer());
> }
> else if (choice == 2){
>     math = new Math(new LowestNumber(), arr);
>     Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + math.returnAnswer());
> }
> ```

Don't Repeat Yourself. That `Console.WriteLine` call doesn't belong in either branch of that conditional:

```
if (choice == 1){
    math = new Math(new HighestNumber(), arr);
}
else if (choice == 2){
    math = new Math(new LowestNumber(), arr);
}
Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + math.returnAnswer());
```

But then again, implementation details are also impacted by the high-level structure of the code - for example with a higher abstraction level and injected dependencies, the entire `ArrayOpsApp` might look like this:

```
public class ArrayOpsApp
{
    private readonly IUserInterface _ui;
    private readonly IDataCollector _collector;
    private reaodnly ICommandSelector _selector;

    public ArrayOpsApp(IUserInterface ui, IDataCollector collector, ICommandSelector selector)
    {
        _ui = ui;
        _collector = collector;
        _selector = selector;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var data = _collector.CollectData();
        var command = _selector.SelectCommand();
        var result = command.Execute(data);
        _ui.OutputResult(result);
    }
}
```

Notice you can write a test that validates that `ArrayOpsApp.Run()` calls the `CollectData` member of its `IDataCollector` dependency, the `SelectCommand` member of its `ICommandSelector` dependency, and the `OutputResult` of its `IUserInterface` dependency. If we also mock the output of the selector's `SelectCommand` method we can also verify that the command's `Execute` method is called, so we can write tests that document what the `Run` method is supposed to be doing; *how* it does it doesn't matter.

Writing SOLID OOP code makes your code *testable*, right. But writing SOLID OOP code is much easier if you *start* by writing the tests, or rather, by *asking yourself* how you would want to be able to test the code. Don't just rush into implementing the functionality - *of course you can implement the functionality*, it's just a very simple exercise after all! It's not about the functionality itself, it's about properly *separating concerns* and doing things right. Remember:

- ***S***ingle Responsibility Principle: a class should have one single reason to change.
- ***O***pen/Closed Principle: the design is extensible, so instead of modifying a class to add functionality, you just add a new one that implements it.
- ***L***iskov Substitution Principle: all implementations of an interface fulfill the same contract - substituting one implementation for another doesn't break the program. `IUserInterface` could very well be a WinForms or a WPF UI, makes no difference. Or a console UI. Or no UI at all, just a mock.
- ***I***nterface Segregation Principle: interfaces should be specialized. Remember modifying an interface is a breaking change.
- ***D***ependency Inversion Principle: depend on abstractions, not concrete types.

([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)))

Comment: SRP covers DRY. It is even more specific and also tells us when DRY is going wrong. Nevertheless: DRY is a good first shot. But in the sense of SRP DRY is only an indicator for code smell not a proof for bad code. The point is: You may have semantic redundancies without code duplication that is a problem. And you have different semantics with code duplication that is fine. On both DRY will not help you. The first you are not able to discover with DRY and the second will lead to errors if you follow DRY.

Answer (score 6):

Additional to @Mat's Mugs great and detailed answer addressing DI, I would just adding few words about alternative solutions.

Because you would like to practice DI, your implementation is absolute OK! However DI / abstractions introduce additional complexity, therefore (IMHO) it should be avoided for logic that doesn't need abstractions.

That is usually the case for [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Your chosen problem (finding min/max value of a list) is such a pure function and therefore I wouldn't use abstraction for that logic in real-world applications.

Alternatively, I would create an extension method or an utility method for such logic.

Fortunately, the extension methods already exists:

```
var max = numbers.Max();
var min = numbers.Min();
```

The utility method could look like:

```
public static void GetMinMax(int[]arr, out int min, out int max)
{
    min = int.MaxValue;
    max = int.MinValue;
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
    {
        if(min >= arr[x]) min = arr[x];
        if(max <= arr[x]) max = arr[x];
    }
}
```

or (supposably) in C# 7

```
public static (int min, int max) GetMinMax(int[]arr)
{
    min = int.MaxValue;
    max = int.MinValue;
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
    {
        if(min >= arr[x]) min = arr[x];
        if(max <= arr[x]) max = arr[x];
    }
    return (min, max);
}
```

---

Some words about your code:

- The class `Math` is absolute useless. It gets an abstraction with an argument and calls the method of the abstraction. That is a good example for "over engineering".
- Methods should start with a capital letter in C# (`GetAnswer`)

---

As @Mat's Mug already mentioned, you could use your abstraction to remove duplications:

```
var options = new Dictionary<int, IMathPerformer>();
options.Add(1, new HighestNumber());
options.Add(2, new LowestNumber());

IMathPerformer performaner;
if (options.TryGetValue(choice, out performaner))
    Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + performaner.GetAnswer());
```

In your case, that is also possible without abstraction:

```
var options = new Dictionary<int, Func<int[], int>>();
options.Add(1, Enumerable.Max);
options.Add(2, Enumerable.Min);

Func<int[], int> func;
if (options.TryGetValue(choice, out func))
    Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + func(arr));
```

Comment: I believe on what you all guys are saying that my Math class is useless, but I wonder what alternative way is possible to get the Min and Max value without that class?

Comment: See my updated answer where the Math class is dropped. The Math class is a second abstraction that is useless, because the logic is already abstracted by the interface  IMathPerformer. You can just use the instance of the interface.

Comment: You might as well return a Tuple instead of using `out` args. (It'll be much cleaner to use a Tuple with C#7.)

Answer (score 1):

I would include null in GetAnswer

Minor performance

```
public int? GetAnswer(int[] arr)
{
    if(arr.Count == 0)
        return null;

    int lowNum = arr[0];
    for (int x = 1; x < arr.Length; x++)
    {
        if (lowNum < arr[x])
        {
            lowNum = arr[x];
        }
    }
    return lowNum;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to ignore null handling. So I would omit "arr == null" and rely on your method signature with typed parameters not to be misused. You expect an int-array so you should get one.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out the thing that other answers do not. As you tell that you want to practice object-oriented knowledge, you had better understand that OOP is about abstraction and encapsulation rather than a way to manage dependencies. Main violation in your code from the OO point of view is data. In OO, there is no data, only objects. Your code should looks like this:

```
var objWithBusinessLogicMeaning = //anything to create such an object
var min = objWithBusinessLogicMeaning.Min;
var max = objWithBusinessLogicMeaning.Max;
// do something usefull with min and max
```